# script not reporting service status correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a script that I use for iperf to be able to start, stop, and check the status of it like a typical service. If I issue a "service iperf start" or a "service iperf stop" it works correctly. When I try to issue a "service iperf status" it always returns it as running even though its not.

When running:

```
#service iperf status
/usr/bin/iperf pid 37567 is running!!!
```

When not running:

```
# service iperf status
/usr/bin/iperf pid is running!!
```

Here is my entire script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# chkconfig: - 50 50
# description: iperf

DAEMON=/usr/bin/iperf
service=iperf
info=$(pidof /usr/bin/iperf)
is_running=`ps aux | grep -v grep | grep iperf | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`

case "$1" in
      start)
              $DAEMON -s -D
              ;;
      stop)
              pidof $DAEMON | xargs kill -9
              ;;
      status)

             if [ $is_running != "1" ];
             then
                echo $DAEMON pid $info is running!!!
              else
                echo $DAEMON is NOT running!!!
              fi
              ;;
      restart)
              $DAEMON stop
              $DAEMON start
              ;;
      *)
              echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
              exit 1
              ;;
esac
```

It seems like its not able to read past the first echo statement in the status section of the script. I have ran the ps command outside of the script from command line to verify I am getting the correct output. If the service is running it returns a "1" just like the script checks for. If its not running it returns a "0" so it should move on to the next echo statement but its not. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

I am on RHEL 6.7 bash version 4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It has something to do with using ps. I think when you call up the "service iperf status" command ps will always find a process with iperf in it. So the value will always be "1" and never be any thing else. So I used netstat to find the process. In my script I am using:

```
IS_RUNNING=$(netstat -anp | grep ":5001" | grep "iperf" | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d"/" -f 2)
```

Which, if running will result in this command finding "iperf"

Then you make the if statement like this:

```
if [ "$IS_RUNNING" = iperf ];
```

And this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the line

```
if [ $is_running != "1" ];
```

to be

```
if [ "$is_running" != "0" ];
```

so that the if fails when there aren't any instances of `iperf` running and it prints the desired status message.  As it is currently written it will only report that `iperf` is not running when there is exactly 1 process of it.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking that if my ps command printout sees a "1" that it would follow the instructions in the if/first echo, and if not go to the second. BTW when the service is running the output of the ps command in the script is a "1" and a "0" if not running. But I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Also note the quotes around `$is_running`

Comment: Its still not working. I have tried with the changes recommended and with many other variations.